# MyBatis SelectProvide pass object as parameter

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-generator

I am using SelectProvider to execute a stored procedure on run-time.

```
@SelectProvider(type = SqlGenerator.class, method = "getProcedure")
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
public void executeProc(@Param("object") Object object);
```

But this is giving the following error

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [web] in context with path [/web] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'searchString' not found. Available parameters are [param1, object]] with root cause
>   org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'searchString' not found. Available parameters are [param1, object]

'search String' is a variable inside the Search object which is passed to the method. When I am directly calling a stored procedure using @Select this is working fine.

```
@Select(value = "{call ALL_SEARCH.SEARCH(
        #{searchString, mode=IN}, 
        #{searchType, mode=IN}, 
        #{personList, mode=OUT, jdbcType=ARRAY, jdbcTypeName=PERSON_TB, typeHandler=com.xyz.PersonArrayHandler}, 
        #{returnCode, mode=OUT, jdbcType=INTEGER}, 
        #{returnMsg, mode=OUT, jdbcType=VARCHAR})}")
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
public void performSearch(Object search);
```

Any help is really appreciable.

Adding getProcedure method

```
public static String getProcedure(Map<String, Object> params) throws ConnectorException {
    String sql = "{call ALL_SEARCH.SEARCH(" 
        + "#{searchString, mode=IN}, " 
        + "#{searchType, mode=IN}, " 
        + "#{personList, mode=OUT, jdbcType=ARRAY, jdbcTypeName=PERSON_TB, typeHandler=com.xyz.PersonArrayHandler}, " 
        + "#{returnCode, mode=OUT, jdbcType=INTEGER}, " 
        + "#{returnMsg, mode=OUT, jdbcType=VARCHAR})};"
    return sql;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide us the code of `getProcedure`.